# Check most common occurrence of a value of one list in a separate list

Tags: python, list

I have a list of numbers.

```
somelist =  [5.000007,5.00099,5.0000075,5.0000075,5.0000075,5.0000099,5.00099,5.0000080,5.0000081,5.00099,5.0000080,5.0000096,5.0000087,5.008,5.00099,5.00000009]
```

I’m using the following to produce a unique list of the 3 lowest values:

```
def lowest_three(somelist):
        lowest_unique = set(somelist)
        return nsmallest(3, lowest_unique)
```

It produces the output:

```
[5.00000009, 5.000007, 5.0000075]
```

Now I want a separate function to tell me which of the three lowest values is the most commonly occuring in the original list.

So I want it to tell me that `5.0000075` is the most common number from the `lowest_three` list in the original list (`somelist`).

I’ve tried the following but it’s not working (it’s currently producing an output of `5.00099` which isn’t even in the `lowest_three` list).

```
def most_common_lowest(somelist):
        for x in lowest_three(somelist):
                return max(set(somelist), key=somelist.count)
```

How can achieve this?

Comment: Your question is not completely specified. What if the lowest three all occur the same number of times? The best of the answers you have received will readily be adapted to corner cases like this; but you will unfairly reject some solutions which do what you asked, but not what you actually need. This wastes everyone's time, and leaves some helpers frustrated because they were not told the complete requirements.

Comment: I think it's unlikely the lowest three will occur the same number of times. The real list will be 360 separate number long.

Comment: You could replace `lowest_three()` with `sorted(somelist)[:3]`.  `max(sorted(somelist)[:3], key=somelist.count)` returns the result you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now I want a separate function to tell me which of the three lowest values is the most commonly occuring in the original list.
>
> ```
> def most_common_lowest(somelist):
>     for x in lowest_three(somelist):
>         return max(set(somelist), key=somelist.count)
> ```

That code doesn't make sense. Should be:

```
def most_common_lowest(somelist):
    return max(lowest_three(somelist), key=somelist.count)
```

Comment: This works and I like the look of it as it seems more simple and elequent than the other answers. Can I just clarify what  `key=somelist.count` does? Does it change the function of `max` so that rather than finding the highest number, it finds the most frequent value?

Comment: @treetop Yeah, no idea why the others made it so complicated or different when you almost had a fine solution already :-). And yes, if you give `max` a `key` function, then it'll apply that function to the values and judge them by the computed key values, in this case how often they appear in `somelist`.

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly collect the counts with [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), with only values from `somelist` that exist in `top_three`, then take the [`most_common`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) of this:

```
from heapq import nsmallest
from collections import Counter

somelist =  [5.000007,5.00099,5.0000075,5.0000075,5.0000075,5.0000099,5.00099,5.0000080,5.0000081,5.00099,5.0000080,5.0000096,5.0000087,5.008,5.00099,5.00000009]

def lowest_three(somelist):
    lowest_unique = set(somelist)
    return nsmallest(3, lowest_unique)

top_three = lowest_three(somelist)
# [5.00000009, 5.000007, 5.0000075]

freqs = Counter(x for x in somelist if x in top_three)
# Counter({5.0000075: 3, 5.000007: 1, 5.00000009: 1})

print(freqs.most_common(1)[0][0])
# 5.0000075
```

O you could group them in a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), and take the max manually:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from operator import itemgetter

filtered_values = [x for x in somelist if x in top_three]
# [5.000007, 5.0000075, 5.0000075, 5.0000075, 5.00000009]

freqs = defaultdict(int)
for val in filtered_values:
    freqs[val] += 1
# defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {5.000007: 1, 5.0000075: 3, 5.00000009: 1})

print(max(freqs.items(), key = itemgetter(1))[0]) # or key = lambda x: x[1]
# 5.0000075
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function min. It might solve your problem out.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
var list = [5.00000009, 5.000007, 5.0000075]
print "min value element : ", min(list)
```

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_min.htm

Answer (score 0):

Given the returned list from `lowest_three`, you can use `list.count`:

```
somelist =  [5.000007,5.00099,5.0000075,5.0000075,5.0000075,5.0000099,5.00099,5.0000080,5.0000081,5.00099,5.0000080,5.0000096,5.0000087,5.008,5.00099,5.00000009]
new_list = lowest_three(somelist)
final_data = sorted(new_list, key=lambda x:somelist.count(x))[-1]
```

Output:

```
5.0000075
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter(somelist)
lowest = lowest_three(somelist)

for num in lowest:
  print counts[num]
```

Answer (score 0):

// i think you better write an algorithm for this operation your self (for the practice)

a simple algorithm :

1. create a map contining only those 3 elements ,(witch you already found), as keys, and 0 as value.
2. run over the array and for each element in the array chack if the map contains him, if it does inc the value by 1 (map[key] = map[key]+1) .
3. iterate over your map and find the key with the highest value.

(it's like a counters array but with map data structure)

Answer (score 0):

Use Counter from collections module and use sorted function, twice once for getting the 3 minimum elements and and second time for getting maximum occurring element

```
from collections import Counter
somelist =  [5.000007,5.00099,5.0000075,5.0000075,5.0000075,5.0000099,5.00099,5.0000080,5.0000081,5.00099,5.0000080,5.0000096,5.0000087,5.008,5.00099,5.00000009]
lowest_three=sorted(Counter(somelist).items(), key=lambda i: i[0])[:3]
print(sorted(lowest_three,key=lambda i :-i[1])[0])
```

**OUTPUT**

```
(5.0000075, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Everyone suggesting you collection module , You can do without collection and in few lines , Here you go:

```
somelist =  [5.000007,5.00099,5.0000075,5.0000075,5.0000075,5.0000099,5.00099,5.0000080,5.0000081,5.00099,5.0000080,5.0000096,5.0000087,5.008,5.00099,5.00000009]

values=[5.00000009, 5.000007, 5.0000075]

track={}
for j,i in enumerate(somelist):
    if i in values:
        if i not in track:
            track[i]=1
        else:
            track[i]+=1
print(max(list(map(lambda x:(track[x],x),track))))
```

output:

```
(3, 5.0000075)
```